# Golang compile with main package code and .a files?

Tags: go

In my scenario I'll need to release my lib project without source code but a compiled form.
Given,

- Some library package in the form of compiled .a files,
- a main package in form of source code,
- all their platform types where they're built on match,

is it possible to compile the main and link it with .a files up into an executable? How to do it if doable?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless the .a files were generated as a result of "installing" (go get or go install) a package. A ".a" library file is "customized" for the OS, machine architecture, go version etc. of the environment in which it will be used. Users of your library are not likely to meet all of the requirements. For that reason, and perhaps others, ".a" files without source code are not useful.

Comment: Thanks, just 2 questions follows up.. 1) Since the .a files are not wild that it originally comes with code and be compiled with main pkg together, so, is there a way I remove the lib source code and the remaining .a files can still be used for linking. (we imagine they're on exactly same environment.) 2) any docs or blog talking about the insights of this question?

Comment: I've never tried to use .a files that weren't created as the result of an install. In other words I've never used a .a file without source code available. You can try by putting the files in the appropriate location**  and see what happens. ** The appropriate location is $GOPATH/pkg/$GOOSARCH/samepath/as/source/file.a

Comment: See [link]http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/ for info on how "installed package objects" (.a files) are generated during the build process.